# Lego bags missing sets

Tags: set-identification, technic

I have some Lego bags that I do not know which set they belong to. Can you guys help me?

[image: https://ibb.co/pQnWwxR]

[image: https://ibb.co/TB7XxJY]

[image: https://ibb.co/3mBw80x]

Answer (score 4):

These are from

[42098: Car Transporter](https://brickset.com/sets/42098-1/Car-Transporter)
[image]

Key parts

- [24116 - Technic, Panel Curved 3 x 5 x 3 in Blue and Light Gray](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=24116&idColor=7#T=C&C=7)
- [15458 - Technic, Panel Plate 3 x 11 x 1 in Dark Azure](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15458&idColor=153#T=C&C=153)